# What is the time-complexity for the following code? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, anagram

Can someone please explain the time and space complexity of the following code and show me the math?

```
let genAnagrams = (word, anagram = '', results = []) => {
  if (!word) {
    results.push(anagram);
    return;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    genAnagrams(word.slice(0, i) + word.slice(i + 1), anagram + word[i], results);
  }
  return [...new Set(results)];
};
```

I know slice adds a linear time complexity at each iteration, so would this then be quadratic?
Would this be O(n! * (n-1)!)? or O(n!)?  or O(n * n!)?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Can't see any attempt at this except some wild guessing.

Comment: I have tried solving this.  The way I see it, given a word of length n, we will loop through this word so the time complexity will be n, multiplied by (n-1) for slicing, plus the recursion, which would be (n-1) * (n-2 + (n-3)(n-3... and so forth.  So if I worked out the math it would be something like:
n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...
I'm not quite sure what this comes down to.